# Tasks section - added 2 tasks, but always install

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to add 2 more optional components in [tasks] section, but they both install even if they aren't selected. Here is what i'm using:

```
[Types]

Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags:iscustom


[Components]

Name: "A"; Description: {#DescriptionA};Types:custom;
Name: "B"; Description: {#DescriptionB};Types:custom; 
Name: "B"; Description: {#DescriptionC};Types:custom; 
Name: "D"; Description: {#DescriptionD};Types:custom; 
Name: "E"; Description: {#DescriptionE};Types:custom; 

[Tasks]

Name:'F'; Description: {#DescriptionF}; 
Name:'G'; Description: {#DescriptionG};

[Files]

Source: {#SourceA}; Components: A; DestDir: {#FinalDestination}; Flags:     onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceB};  Components: B; DestDir: {#FinalDestination}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceC}; Components: C; DestDir: {#FinalDestination}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceD}; Components: D; DestDir: {#Destination}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceE}; Components: E; DestDir: {#Destination}; Flags:
onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceF}; DestDir: {#Destination}; Flags:  onlyifdoesntexist;
Source: {#SourceG}; DestDir: {#Destination}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You missed to add [`Tasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) parameter (if we are talking about the last two entries of your `[Files]` section.

Comment: Sorry I was just editing.

Comment: No problem, but I still don't see any `Tasks` parameter (do not mix with `[Tasks]` section). I can see only `[Tasks]` section, but your (last two) `[Files]` section entries (if we are talking about them) does not have the `Tasks` parameter (that's the optional parameter, similar to `Components` parameter). Follow the link from my first comment for its description.

Comment: So would I have to do it like this? Tasks: F;

Comment: Thank you TLama. That worked. I'm one step closer to finishing this now.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to conditionally install files then You have to add task/components parameter with the files to work according to the checkbox checked or unchecked.Without parameter(`Tasks: '*'` or `Components: '*'`) `Files` will install every time.

So here is the correct script that will conditionally install files according to components and tasks checkboxs:

```
[Types]
Name: custom; Description: Custom installation; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: A; Description: {#DescriptionA}; Types: custom
Name: B; Description: {#DescriptionB}; Types: custom
Name: C; Description: {#DescriptionC}; Types: custom
Name: D; Description: {#DescriptionD}; Types: custom
Name: E; Description: {#DescriptionE}; Types: custom

[Tasks]
Name: 'F'; Description: {#DescriptionF}
Name: 'G'; Description: {#DescriptionG}

[Files]
Source: "{#SourceA}"; DestDir: "{#FinalDestination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Components: A
Source: "{#SourceB}"; DestDir: "{#FinalDestination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Components: B
Source: "{#SourceC}"; DestDir: "{#FinalDestination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Components: C
Source: "{#SourceD}"; DestDir: "{#Destination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Components: D
Source: "{#SourceE}"; DestDir: "{#Destination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist:; Components: E
Source: "{#SourceF}"; DestDir: "{#Destination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Tasks: 'F'
Source: "{#SourceG}"; DestDir: "{#Destination}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist; Tasks: 'G'
```